# Restricting Links to certain Objects

Tags: ibm-doors

So, Modules are filled with Objects, only some of which are requirements. Links to non-requirements are meaningless... but naturally users insist on doing that, regardless. Lazy, careless, or simply undertrained; our users are humans, who will often enter highly imperfect data.

What's the best way to forbid such mislinks? Is there a native way? I fear not, although it seems rather basic. Pop up an annoying warning whenever they try, via DXL?

We have an enumerated Attribute that will tell us if the target is a requirement or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triggers to accomplish this!

For a very brief idea, see [this relatively recent conversation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=55d056e5-d8c4-447d-9a39-8e765ecdd811)

You will want a pre-create trigger on the link confirming whether it's target object has the correct enumerated type. This could be a database level trigger, or project level, or even module level if there is only one particularly bothersome section.

Keep in mind this is only for more up-to-date versions of DOORS. Older versions will require something a bit more complex- for example, a trigger that checks a module pre-close to see if any links have been created, and if so if they have 'valid' targets according to your criteria. You could have a post-open dxl that creates an array of links and stores it in the DXL top context... but that might be a bit advanced.

Comment: Thank you! That gels a vague idea I had in my head... Tomorrow I'll check our version.